# Only add NEW JSON entries from a URL to a CouchDB using PHP (don't store duplicates)

Tags: php, json, couchdb

Server A produces JSON, exposes it via a URL.

My Server, B, queries this URL, grabs JSON, via PHP.

I want to stick this in a CouchDB, also running on B, via PHP.

The issue is that the way A works is it gives you the last, say, 200 entries. If I query it on Monday, and get 200 entries, and then query it Tuesday and get 200 more, it's possible only 50 of those are "new", so I don't want to stick the other 150 (that are the same) in the DB. What's the best way of going about this, using PHP and CouchDB/JSON?

The JSON entries [that the URL exposes] have a systemID field, that increases for each element.  So if I query the URL and receive 200 entries, the last element in the array should have the highest systemID (not to be confused with a CouchDB _id).  I can also obviously add fields (microtime?) to the JSON before I stick it in the CouchDB, but I still need to know what to query in the DB to make sure I don't store duplicates.

I think I need to create a view based on these systemIDs, sort by descending, and then see which of my incoming JSON has a systemID greater than the last element of the view, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

So, let's say the CouchDB has this at this moment:

```
[
   {
    "AuthorName": "Thomson",
    "CreatedOn": "2013-07-23T22:21:51.822+00:00",
     "SystemID: "101"
  },
  {
    "AuthorName": "Johnson",
    "CreatedOn": "2013-07-23T22:22:51.822+00:00",
     "SystemID: "102"
  }
]
```

How do I run a query on the CouchDB to get "102"?  Once I have that, I know how to handle the rest.  Thanks!

Comment: 1) Receieve JSON through file_get_contents(), 2) json_decode(), 3) Query the DB and use `IN` to check existence of multiple values for one column, 4) check if true/false, 5) insert/don't

Comment: Okay, well, I've already done the first two things.  It's the third I'm having trouble with.  What do you mean "multiple values for one column"?  Do you mean if the systemIDs already exist?  Wouldn't it be more efficient to just get the "last" systemID already in the CouchDB and then add anything that's greater?  Either way, that's not super helpful answer.

Comment: My comment was not an answer, it was merely a direction you could take. I don't know if you ever update anything, and if you don't, then yes, perform a query, retreieve the last row, compare that id to the first row you recieve from the JSON response, if it does not match, then perform the insertion of all the rows supplied through JSON.

Comment: Well, thanks, I guess.  Hopefully someone can help me with the query structure for CouchDB and how best to get the desired information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I sorted this out.  Here's how to do it:

First, I created a view, like this:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.BurnedID) {
     emit(doc.BurnedID);

  }
}
```

Then, my PHP script queries a URL like this:

```
http://myserver.com/mydb/_design/SystemID/_view/Get%20SystemID?descending=true&limit=1
```

Which returns a JSON document that, eventually, contains the key of the highest SystemID currently in the CouchDB.

I can then use that to check against my incoming JSON, and only add newer entries to the database.

Note, this could also work if the [incoming] JSON didn't already have a SystemID.  I would use the microtime(true) PHP function to generate a timestamp (really, just an increasing large floating point number) and add that to the JSON before I put it in the database.  I could then  use that in the same fashion.

Hope this helps someone!